# Is there a final, simple answer of how to detect if a function exists?

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++20

This site has 50+ post about the topic, several 'detection patterns' have had their successes through various epochs. With C++20 we should see quite some simplifications here.

So, what are the current best practices of detecting

- A. Global functions
- B. Member functions

1. An exact signature. E.g. detect that `F( int )` is defined rather than any `F` that takes an int via (an implicit) conversion.
2. Callable with a given type (under the usual rules of implicit conversion)

Comment: Can you give an example of when you'd want to do this? I likely won't be able to answer then, because I'm not as deep into the language as some people, but I think it would improve the question and give people like me some insight into the context.

Comment: "*Callable under the usual rules of implicit conversion*" ... what does this mean? Callable with what? Implicit conversion applies to objects, the arguments to a function. Overload resolution is the process of taking a function set and a set of arguments, and deciding which function to call. Without arguments, overload resolution and implicit conversion don't apply.

Comment: "*This site has 50+ post about the topic, several 'detection patterns' have had their successes through various epochs.*" Can you link to some? I did a quick SO search for "detection pattern" in the C++ tag, and got nothing. The only questions I can recall seeing are questions that ultimately amount to "C++ doesn't have concepts, so how do I work around that." That is, you're not trying to detect exact function signatures; you're trying to find if certain code is legitimate. The former matters only to the extent that it permits the latter. Concepts let you ask the latter directly.

Comment: "*Callable with a given type*" Functions are not called with "types"; they're called with *expressions*. The value category of these expressions (along with their types) factor into overload resolution.

Comment: If these clarifications would lead to an answer of some sort it would be appreciated. As it stands they just look like Asperger's.

Comment: @non-user38741: These aren't "clarifications"; they're requests for you to explain what you're talking about, because some of the things you've stated are either without foundation or just don't make sense. And I have no idea what "Asperger's" has to do with any of this.

Comment: What does it say about a site if one of the worst communicators is communicating the most? Or rather 'trying to communicate'

Answer (score 1):

Basically requires expressions:

```
// 1
bool exists = requires(Sig &sig) { sig = thefunction; }
// 2
bool exists = requires(A a) { thefunction(a); }
// 2B
bool exists = requires(C &c, A a) { c.thefunction(a); }
```

`Sig` should be:

```
using Sig = RV (*) (Args); // A
using Sig = RV (Class::*) (Args); // B
```

Comment: I don't have anything meaningful to say in respect to the information itself, but I'd like to comment on the form - I think that the word "*basically*" works wonders here. It emphasises that we **finally** have a **simple** way of achieving something like that, which was so, so desired amongst C++ programmers, who deal with quite a lot of metaprogramming-related issues.

Comment: So far so simple. Now for the difference between 1. and 2., which I have tried to make clearer via an edit. By "exact signature" I did not mean output signature. Rather taking the exact arguments without implicit conversions.

Comment: @non-user38741: The type `Sig` is intended to *be* the signature of the function.

Comment: @non-user38741: That being said, it should be noted that the `Sig` version only works if ADL isn't a factor.

Comment: @Dani: there are a number of confounding variables that make your #1 non-functional. If `thefunction` is a template, for example, this won't work. Nor will it work if it is found via ADL based on a parameter from the signature.

Comment: @Fureeish Obviously, *"basically"* means that one cannot be bothered with the details. 2 and 2B seem straightforward enough. I still cannot make sense of the `Sig` in 1, though. Hints would be appreciated, even condescending ones.

Comment: @non-user38741: there you go.

Comment: These always give me fits, a pretty dangerous combination with the half-baked `requires` support of MSVC. Thanks anyway. Maybe using `using` will require using less pills.